# understanding git issue with rebase on branch with accidental and undone commits

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

We have some issues with a branch which got messed up somehow in the past... the following situation:

- D is a delivery branch where we receive changes from providers
- M is the master branch
- F is a feature branch
- commits from D are merged to M
- F is rebased with M
- M contains an accidental commit of F (F2), M3 is the revert of that commit

```
             D
    D1-D2-D3-o
     \      \___________
      \                 \  M
       \-M1-M2-D2-F2-M3-D3-o
        \        /
         \      /    F
          \-F1-F2-F3-o
```

Now we are again trying to rebase F with M but the change F2 that we reverted with M3 is missing in the end.

```
    
             D
    D1-D2-D3-o
     \      \___________
      \                 \  M
       \-M1-M2-D2-F2-M3-D3-o
                         \
                          \        F
                           \-F1-F3-o
```

When in branch F we simply use:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Is there an explanation why rebasing F1-F2-F3 onto F2-M3 will loose F2?

What seems to work is to squash all changes in F to a single commit and do the rebase then, in this case the changes introduced in F2 are still present.

I tried to rewrite the history of M using rebase interactive mode and preserving the merges... my idea was to remove both the accidental commit (F2) and the revert of it (M3) but the result didn't give me any confidence that I did not loose anything.

Also I came across the following (mentioned under bugs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) which made me discard the idea of rewriting the history of master.

> The todo list presented by --preserve-merges --interactive does not
>   represent the topology of the revision graph. Editing commits and
>   rewording their commit messages should work fine, but attempts to
>   reorder commits tend to produce counterintuitive results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will guess that `F2` on `M` is a cherry-pick of `F2` on `F` and not a merge as the graph suggests.

When rebasing, git will cherry-pick all commits that are in `F` but not in `M`, as `F2` is in both branches it doesn't pick it.

If you want to keep it, a solution is to use all arguments of the `git rebase`:

```
git rebase --onto M $(git merge-base F M) F
# equivalent to:
# git rebase --onto M D1 F
```

This will rebase all the commits in `F`, but not in the common ancestor of `M` and `F` (`D1`) ==> `F1-F2-F3`, at the end of `M`

---

Another solution is to do an interactive rebase (`git rebase --interactive M F`), then explicitly add the `pick F2` in the rebase-todo:

```
pick F1
pick F2
pick F3
```

Comment: The graph is just an example of the situation, not sure how the change got there. But your explanation is understandable, thx! My colleague that is working on the branch already moved on after the squash workaround... will try your proposed rebase next time we run into such a situation.